# Ліфт — міжповерховий дрототяг?

Tags: значення-слів

Пам`ятаю, ще років 5 чи 10 тому почали говорити про те, що ліфт — це міжповерховий дрототяг. Звичайно, це більше схоже на жарт.

Ліфт (англ. lift — «підйомник», від to lift — «підіймати») — технічна споруда зі спеціальною кабіною для вертикального переміщення людей або вантажів.

В мережі знайшла цікаві варіанти перекладу, серед яких, до речі, також був міжповерховий дрототяг)) Це: підойма, витяг, підіймач, здійма, верхохід, дротохід, поверхід, левата, тяг.

Яке слово доречно вживати? "Ліфт" чи якесь інше?

Comment: Чи Українці використовують слово «вінда», з Польської «windą»?

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Майже самостійна [неповна] відповідь і додаток до [відповіді](/a/4029/585) пана [Sasha](/users/4/sasha) і [дописки](/q/4028#comment6947_4028) пана [enap-mwf](/users/978/enap-mwf)</sup>

[Словник](//storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1319) Павла Штепи радить замість *ліфт* вживати *підойма*. Не бачу проблем для вживу, оскільки слово просте і зрозуміле, також [частково] підтверджується словником в 11 книгах.

> [**Підо́йма**](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidojma), **и**, *жін.*
>
> Найпростіше знаряддя у вигляді стрижня, що може обертатися навколо нерухомої точки опори і служити для піднімання, підважування чого-небудь, зрівноважуючи більшу силу за допомогою меншої; підвага, важіль. — *Підкопуйте його [камінь] з долу, підкладайте підойми!* (Іван Франко, VI, 1951, 116);

*Витяг* і *тяг* може згодитися, коли братимемо до уваги чеське [*výtah*](//cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%BDtah). Сучасне [*витяг*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vytjagh) з дещо книжковим означенням не є сильною завадою: *невеликий уривок, частина чи цитата з якого-небудь тексту*.

---

> Чи Українці використовують слово *вінда* з Польської *winda*?

Як загальне, але розмовне слово — так, але в [означені](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53394/373999.html) *операційної системи [Windows](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)*. А за польським означенням [*winda*](//pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winda) — ні, хіба що як частина західних — [львівського](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53394/1061204.html) чи [галицького](http://slovopedia.org.ua/100/53394/1041668.html) — розмовних говірок.

Answer (score 2):

«Міжповерховий дрото**хід**» — здається так це звучало в оригінальному жарті. Так, звісно, це був жарт. Принаймні це словосполучення (ані з -хід, ані з -тяг) відсутнє у загальному вжитку (хоча не виключено, що воно вживається/вживалося десь локально (можливо, дуже локально) перед тим як стати предметом жарту, але оскільки жодних підтверджень цього я не бачив, то припускаю, що це чистий жарт).

«**[Ліфт](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=48159&page=1519)**» — нормативне слово. Зі «Словника української мови» в 20 томах від Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду:

> ЛІФТ, а, ч. Технічна споруда зі спеціальною кабіною для вертикального переміщення людей або вантажів. *Зайшли брати і сестриці-сміяниці в ліфт, поїхали нагору* (В. Нестайко); *Вільного часу — секунд тридцять, поки Чертог ліфтом підніметься* (Люко Дашвар); * У порівн. *Легко, як ліфт у багатоповерховому будинку, кліть шугнула в підземелля* (С. Чорнобривець).

Чи існують якісь діалектні альтернативи для слова «ліфт», мені невідомо (можливо, хтось інший висвітить це в іншій відповіді). [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) від УМІФ наводять лише такі (часткові) синоніми:

> ЛІФТ (споруда зі спеціальною кабіною для підіймання людей або вантажів), **підйо́мник** техн., **підійма́ч** техн. *Севочка втягнув у ліфт чемодани, натиснув кнопку сьомого поверху* (В. Собко); *Йому теж від входу в тунель доведеться дертися на гору. Підйомник давно знято* (І. Ле); *Монтування підіймача*.